# Defining "method_called".. How do I make a hook method which gets called every time any function of a class gets called?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, hook

I want to make a hook method which gets called everytime any function of a class gets called.
I have tried method_added, but it executes only once at the time of class definition,

```
class Base

  def self.method_added(name)
    p "#{name.to_s.capitalize} Method's been called!!"
  end
  def a
    p "a called."
  end
  def b
    p "b called."
  end
end
t1 = Base.new
t1.a
t1.b
t1.a
t1.b

Output:

"A Method's been called!!"
"B Method's been called!!"
"a called."
"b called."
"a called."
"b called."
```

but my requirement is that any function of a class that gets called anywhere in the program triggers the "method_called", hook method.

```
Expected Output:
"A Method's been called!!"
"a called."
"B Method's been called!!"
"b called."
"A Method's been called!!"
"a called."
"B Method's been called!!"
"b called."
```

If there is any defined existing hook method that works just the same, then please tell about it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Ya I definitely looked up to them and thanks for your answer.

Comment: mikej means that you should go back through your previous questions and click the checkbox on any answers that adequately address your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at [`Kernel#set_trace_func`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func). It lets you specify a proc which is invoked whenever an event (such as a method call) occurs. Here's an example:

```
class Base
  def a
    puts "in method a"
  end

  def b
    puts "in method b"
  end
end

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  # only interested in events of type 'call' (Ruby method calls)
  # see the docs for set_trace_func for other supported event types
  puts "#{classname} #{id} called" if event == 'call'
}

b = Base.new
b.a
b.b
```

Outputs:

```
Base a called
in method a
Base b called
in method b
```

Answer (score 18):

`method_added` is there to run code when a new method has been added to the class; it doesn't report when a method has been called. (As you discovered.)

If you don't want to follow mikej's answer, here is a class that implements your specification:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Base
  def self.method_added(name)
    if /hook/.match(name.to_s) or method_defined?("#{name}_without_hook")
      return
    end
    hook = "def #{name}_hook\n p 'Method #{name} has been called'\n #{name}_without_hook\nend"
    self.class_eval(hook)

    a1 = "alias #{name}_without_hook #{name}"
    self.class_eval(a1)

    a2 = "alias #{name} #{name}_hook"
    self.class_eval(a2)
  end
  def a
    p "a called."
  end
  def b
    p "b called."
  end
end
t1 = Base.new
t1.a
t1.b
t1.a
t1.b
```

And output:

```
$ ./meta.rb
"Method a has been called"
"a called."
"Method b has been called"
"b called."
"Method a has been called"
"a called."
"Method b has been called"
"b called."
```

Comment: I like this.  It seems less invasive than a global `set_trace_func` since this hackery is constrained to just this class.

Comment: very clever! It's too bad there isn't a language feature that makes this a tad easier to do without being heavyweight.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote something that might be useful, though there are some provisos (see below).
Here's the class you want to add your hook to:

```
class Original  
  def regular_old_method msg
    puts msg
  end

private

  def always_called method_called
    puts "'#{method_called.to_s.capitalize}' method's been called!"
  end
end
```

And here's the code for adding that hook:

```
class << Original
  def new(*args)
    inner = self.allocate
    outer_name = self.name + 'Wrapper'
    outer_class = Class.new do
      def initialize inner_object
        @inner = inner_object
      end
      def method_missing method_called, *args
        @inner.send method_called, *args
        @inner.send :always_called, method_called
      end
    end
    outer_class_constant = Object.const_set(outer_name, outer_class)
    inner.send :initialize, *args
    outer_class_constant.new inner
  end
end
```

If you call it like this...

```
o = Original.new
o.regular_old_method "nothing unusual about this bit"
```

You get the following output:

> nothing unusual about this bit
>
> 'Regular_old_method' method's been called!

This approach would be a bad idea if your code checked class names, because even though you've asked for an object of class 'Original', what you got back was an object of class 'OriginalWrapper'.

Plus I imagine there could be other drawbacks to messing with the 'new' method, but my knowledge of Ruby metaprogramming doesn't stretch that far yet.