# Ruby: hooks for methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to find a gem or to write a code that implements hooks for methods.

```
class A
  include SomeModule
  before_hook :meth, lambda { puts 'bla' }

  def meth
    puts 'meth'
  end
end

# A.new.meth => "bla\nmeth\n"
```

I am using Rails and I know about callbacks and filters but

- `meth` isn't an action
- I don't wand to change how I method call

Help me please...

**UPDATE**

I find a gem for automating this code:

```
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :meth_callback

  set_callback :meth_callback, :before do |object|
    # my code
  end

  def meth_with_callback
    run_callbacks(:meth_callback) { meth }
  end

  alias_method_chain :meth, :callback
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining "method_called".. How do I make a hook method which gets called every time any function of a class gets called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236194/defining-method-called-how-do-i-make-a-hook-method-which-gets-called-every-t)

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471857/1322562

Comment: @jdoe Yes that's it what I want but isn't there a gem whit this functionality?

Comment: @АлександрКуракин - you will get better answers if you go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: @АлександрКуракин This is too simple task for a gem. It's already a part of Rails. What would any one want to extract it?..

Comment: @jdoe, I don't think there's some kind of minimum complexity for gems. Small libraries that do one thing well are a good thing; if ActiveSupport was broken up into small parts, people would be able to use what they actually wanted to use without having to depend on the entire thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ActiveModel::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html)

```
define_model_callbacks :create

def create
  run_callbacks :create do
    # do your thing here
  end
end
```

You can even write a little helper method to hide this `run_callbacks` line. It may look like this:

```
hooked_method :create do
  # do your thing here
end
```

Comment: Thank you but caller haven't call something else `meth`... An idea is to use `alias_method` and callbacks (internally). But I want to find a gem...

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by "but caller haven't call something else meth" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Call of `meth` have to do something like `run_callbacks(:callback_name) { meth }`.

Comment: No, `meth` will do it. Read the snippet again. And provided link also.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `meth` is called by superclass. It shouldn't know about my `run_callbacks` and `hook_methods`...

Comment: Who shouldn't know? `meth` or superclass?